# Making my own Breakout board for a GPS

Tags: prototyping, breakout

I am prototyping a few things and wanted to make my own breakout for something that  I haven't done before: GPS. ([link to page](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/RXM-GPS-R4-T/RXM-GPS-R4-TCT-ND/3979651))
I know that high-freq. PCB are usually different compared to regular PCB.
My question to you guys are as follows:
Is the ground plane nessecary?

Should I put decoupling caps on the PCB or leave them to the prototype?

What should I change to acomodate to the 5GHz frequency /antenna?

How can I put power protection on this aside from a fuse?

Is this a viable setup for prototyping?

Schematic:
[image]

[image]

refrence:
red: fill
black:nofill
small white text: solder pad
large white text: silk layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the ground plane nessecary?

Yes, only to control the characteristic impedance of the antenna trace. Without a ground plane it is very difficult to ensure 50Ω. For such a short trace, you may get away with it, but you might find that depending on where you place your prototyping board, or how close you hand comes to it, has a big effect on the reception performance of the antenna.

To save yourself the trouble of adding a ground plane, for the sake of prototyping I'd just move the connector closer to the pin and live with the possible degradation to reception.

> Should I put decoupling caps on the PCB or leave them to the prototype?

Put them on. The inductance of the pin headers will make external caps pretty useless.

> What should I change to acomodate to the 5GHz frequency /antenna?

Make that antenna trace as short as possible.

> How can I put power protection on this aside from a fuse?

I don't see power protection as necessary. You're likely to kill the chip due to over voltage before you manage to blow a fuse. If you're concerned about that, add some Zeners and a fuse.

> Is this a viable setup for prototyping?

Don't see why not.

PS. That gnd traces on pins 18 and 20 look painfully thin.

PPS. Nice schematic symbol for the antenna!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! my antenna symbol is strange, I know! :-p. 18 and 20 each have 3 traces, thoug i'd like to thicken them up as well.

Comment: i've added some revisions. the antenna trace now looks like so: http://prntscr.com/9fybns